# Regex lookup string in predefined list

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I need to remove a paritcular string from a regular expression. The particular strins are predefined in a list

```
list = [ 'EUR', 'USD', 'GBP' ]
```

i have another list with hundrets of names containing the above strings:

```
ref = [ ' asdf EUR Test',
        ' jkl USD Test',
        ' qwert GBP Test' ]
```

Now I want to achieve the following results:

- asdf
- jkl
- qwert

I've started with somthing like:

```
def clean_it(string):
    string = string.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode()
    x = re.findall('|'.join(list)+r'\sTest\b')
    string = re.sub(x,'',string)
    string = re.sub(r'\sTest\b','',string)
    clean_it = string
    return clean_it
```

unfortunately I am getting the following error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `x` is a list, and you are trying to use it as a string (or pattern object) in `string = re.sub(x,'',string)`. You should just do the substitution in one line, rather than finding all the matches and then trying to replace them:

```py
import re

words = [ 'EUR', 'USD', 'GBP' ]

ref = [ ' asdf EUR Test',
        ' jkl USD Test',
        ' qwert GBP Test' ]

def clean_it(string):
    return re.sub(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(words) + r')\s+Test\b', '', string)

ref = map(clean_it, ref)
print(list(ref))
```

Output:

```py
[' asdf ', ' jkl ', ' qwert ']
```